# Cloning github repositories to pc and making them executable on linux

Tags: linux, shell, github, repository, cloning

I tried to clone a repo from git using `git clone`, and after it downloaded I tried to run the command, although the command was not found. After adding the file to the path via `export PATH = "..."` the command did not work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To specify the location of executables, you must specify the PATH as set of colon ":" separated directories.

Here's a reasonable template for you to follow:

```
export PATH=$PATH:<add-your-new-dir-here>
```

Typically, the PATH is always exported, so you'll only need to do this:

```
PATH=$PATH:<add-your-new-dir-here>
```

In your question, you indicated that you are adding a "file" to the PATH.  Remember, you must add directories.

Comment: Thanks a lot it did the job.

Comment: @Fildo7525 - Feel free to accept if this did the trick for you (it's been a slow year for me).